# My electron js .dmg file is not containing all the meta data such as package.json

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am trying to run a script over terminal in my electron js project which works fine if i run the build on my local device but if i share that particular application which i dmg file it is not contaning all the metadata which is required for the app such as whole release folde

For Build i am using
-> electron-builder
"build": {
"productName": "ElectronReact",
"appId": "org.erb.ElectronReact",
"asar": false,
"asarUnpack": "**\*.{node,dll}",
"files": [
"dist",
"node_modules",
"package.json"
],
"afterSign": ".erb/scripts/notarize.js",
"mac": {
"target": {
"target": "default",
"arch": [
"arm64",
"x64"
]
},
"type": "distribution",
"hardenedRuntime": true,
"entitlements": "assets/entitlements.mac.plist",
"entitlementsInherit": "assets/entitlements.mac.plist",
"gatekeeperAssess": false
},
"dmg": {
"contents": [
{
"x": 130,
"y": 220
},
{
"x": 410,
"y": 220,
"type": "link",
"path": "/Applications"
}
]
},
"win": {
"target": [
"nsis"
]
},
"linux": {
"target": [
"AppImage"
],
"category": "Development"
},
"directories": {
"app": "release/app",
"buildResources": "assets",
"output": "release/build"
},
"extraResources": [
"./assets/**"
],
"publish": {
"provider": "github",
"owner": "electron-react-boilerplate",
"repo": "electron-react-boilerplate"
}
},

Packaged app is not containing all the Metadata which is required and described inside package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the command what you are passing for dmg packaged application as things are going to execute with node cmd(your cmd)